# jBox-Tooltips closing on Mouseleave despite "closeOnMouseleave: false"

Tags: javascript, jbox

I have a problem with jBox-tooltips: my setting of `closeOnMouseleave: false` is ignored, so when I want to move the mouse over one of the URLs in the tip, the tip closes!

```js
 $(function(){                               
      $('.tooltipMultiX').jBox('Tooltip', {  
    getTitle: 'data-jbox-title',             
    getContent: 'data-jbox-content' ,        
    closeButton: 'title' ,                   
    closeOnClick: 'body' ,                   
    closeOnMouseleave: false ,               
   closeOnEsc: true                          
});                                          
 });
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jboxcdn.com/0.3.2/jBox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jboxcdn.com/0.3.2/jBox.min.js"></script>
<span class="tooltipMultiX" data-jbox-title="Select sample to open" data-jbox-content="<a href='/Examples/DC/DatatableSimple'>The simplest use case of a DataTable</a><br /><a href='/Examples/DC/DatatableAdvancedIndex'>Alternative list of controls and samples with filtering/search</a><br />">2</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! :(
I misunderstood the `closeOnMouseleave`-Option - when setting it to true, it works fine.